# What is the significance of .htaccess of wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess

Here is `.htaccess` from my local `wordpress` installation.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wordpress/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Even when I have removed these directives from the `.htaccess` file still `wordpress` works fine, why is that so? why was this added if wordpress can work fine without it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is utilizing Apache's `mod_rewrite` so your Wordpress installation can make use of nice-looking URLs that look something like `http://www.example.com/2015/8/12/my-post-title/` instead of `http://www.example.com/?post=173663`. This improves your SEO and users' experiences on your site, and the vast majority of major blogging software supports it!

Comment: Thanks for response, question was, why does it still work when I have removed `.htaccess` directives?

Comment: I'm betting Wordpress still works but those pretty URLs don't. Give that a test - otherwise that `mod_rewrite` directive must still be around somewhere.

Comment: And yes, you're right - Wordpress can work perfectly fine without this feature. It's just much nicer with it turned on.

Comment: There was one other `.htaccess` file up in the hierarchy I deleted that too, still pretty URLs like this one are working, http://localhost/wordpress/2015/07/13/hello-world/

Comment: Weird. There may still be more .htaccess (check with `find . | grep 'htaccess'` from the root) or maybe you have something that's caching above the PHP layer?

Comment: Man! you were right, I uploaded `wordpress` files to server,removed `.htaccess` and pretty permalinks stopped working.